# How to draw ROC curve using value of confusion matrix?

Tags: r

Consider i have a classifier like `A` and the result of its classification gives me the following table:

```
    TP  TN  FP  FN
A   225 100 175 100
```

TP is True Positive

TN is True Negative

FP is False Postive

FN is False Negative

**How i can draw a plot curve of ROC?**

I know, i can define a variable, and try to predict it based on A, and then make a dataframe which exactly simulate the above values, and finally, i can use [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/105760/how-we-can-draw-an-roc-curve-for-decision-trees) code. But i think **there should be an easier way?**

Comment: ROC curves are drawn for probabilities, not "thresholded" predictions.
Try to get the raw output from your model.

Comment: @janlauge can be any kind of score, not just probabilities.

Answer (score 5):

This is impossible, because you only have a confusion matrix for a certain (unknown) threshold of your classifier. A ROC-Curve contains information about all possible thresholds.

The Confusion matrix corresponds to a single point on your ROC Curve:

Sensitivity = TP / (TP + FN)
1 - Specificy = TN / (TN + FP) .

Comment: What do you think about this?
https://www.researchgate.net/post/How_can_I_draw_a_ROC_curve_having_TP_Rate_and_FP_Rate_Values

Comment: You should build such a table for different threshold, getting different points and thus, the shape of the ROC curve.

Comment: @user5363938 In the linked discussion, we are given a score per observation and the true value. You only supplied a confusion matrix in your question.

Comment: So, how can i mock a dataframe which leads to the same confusion matrix?

Comment: Not sure where you are going, but you could make all Positive values 1 and all negative values 0. This won't give you any more insight, though...

The Test/Actual combinations are TP: 1-1, FP: 1-0, TN: 0-0, FN: 0-1. If you create a data.frame by `rep`ing these rows as often as needed, you will be able to draw a ROC curve, but it won't be very useful.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you'd simulate a new variable. You're basically asking to plot a curve from a single point, which is impossible. Instead, you should  just use the dependent variable in the training or test data that you used to train the model. This will allow you to find a cutoff point that you consider optimal.

The pROC package allows us to plot ROC curves easily. 
Assuming we have a data frame named test and a model named mymodel, we could use something like this:

```
library('pROC')
plot(roc(test$y, predict(mymodel, test, type = "prob"))
```

Comment: Note that ROC requires a predicted _probability_ and not a predicted _class_.

Comment: @AlexR doesn't have to be a probability, it can be any kind of score. But preferably not the predicted class indeed.