# Generating ROC Curve From Confusion Matrix in Python

Tags: python-3.x, roc, confusion-matrix

Firstly I am using Python 3.7 and installed PROC plugin. I am totally noob in Python coding. Would deeply appreciate if you guys can tell me what to write for generating ROC curve.

This is my exact result,

Accuracy = 0.41145393068469993

Confusion Matrix:

['a' 'b' 'c' 'd' 'e']

[[353 168  80 112 245]

[190 302  20 352  75]

[245  96 300  47 278]

[129 350  20 412  49]

[ 66 129  75  59 580]]

Precision:  [0.35910478 0.28899522 0.60606061 0.41955193 0.47269764]

Recall:  [0.36847599 0.32161874 0.31055901 0.42916667 0.63806381]

F1 Score:  [0.36373004 0.30443548 0.41067762 0.42430484 0.54307116]

Heres the sample code where I generate my output,

```
print("Accuracy = "+str(accuracy))

# Showing the Confusion Matrix
print("\nConfusion Matrix:")
cm = confusion_matrix(testClass, testGuess, labels=classifier.classes_)
prec, rec, f1, tureSum= precision_recall_fscore_support(testClass, testGuess)
print(classifier.classes_)
print(cm)
print("Precision: ",prec)
print("Recall: ",rec)
print("F1 Score: ",f1)
print()
```

Comment: You can't. See for instance https://stackoverflow.com/q/43201576/333599

Comment: Okay.. Can I manually generate the ROC curve copying the Matrix output (I want to plot the a, b, c, d, e)? I mean is there any web interface or Excel trick? Thank you in advance.. :)